# MapQuest Android API and Mapnik

Tags: openstreetmap, mapquest, mapnik

I have implemented MapQuest's Android API. In the documentation for the general API it says when using the OpenStreetMap data it is possible to use "Custom map tiles via the Mapnik style files". I was wondering if that meant that you could host your own tile server running Mapnik and get the API to use those tiles or something else. There is no more mention of this in any of the documentation that I can find. Can someone help me clear this up please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to using Mapnik style files has to do with the fact that MapQuest offers the style files to developers who want to tweak them and then generate their own tiles based on OpenStreetMap data.  This isn't specific to the Android API, however, and the Android API does not support custom map tiles.  I apologize for the confusion (I work at MapQuest).

Comment: Helo i do also have the same kind of work, i need to include my own tile server with MapQuest on my android map app by ignoring map generated from MapQuest. I was following their official code samples https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/ and saw the controls like markers, polylines & polygons working perfectly on top their map. Now im stucked with integrating my tile server. Please help me out! Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you are right and you can't use custom tile styles but custom UI styles ([UI styles guide](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/custom))